# "To every Q-matrix corresponds a unique Markov process." Proving uniqueness

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

"To every Q-matrix corresponds a unique Markov process." I'm trying to understand Klenke's proof of the uniqueness part of this proposition.

---

**Klenke's proof**

*Following is an adapted version of [Klenke](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848000472)'s proof of the uniqueness part. The original can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mptln.jpg) ("Now assume that...").*

Let $(p_t)_{t\geq0}, (r_t)_{t\geq0}$ be Markov semigroups. Let $q$ be a bounded infinitesimal generator such that
$$\lim_{s\downarrow0}\frac{1}{s}(p_s-I)=q=\lim_{s\downarrow0}\frac{1}{s}(r_s-I)$$

It can be shown that $\frac{d}{dt}p_t=qp_t$ and $\frac{d}{dt}r_t=qr_t$ for all $0\leq t$, and so
$$p_t-r_t=\intop_0^t q(p_s-r_s)\space d s$$

Define $u_s:=p_s-r_s$. Then $\|u_s\|_2\leq2$ and $\|q\|_2\leq2\lambda$ (where $\lambda:=\sup |q_{i,i}|<\infty$ by assumption). Hence
$$\sup_{s\leq t}\|u_s\|_2\leq\sup_{s\leq t}\intop_0^s\|qu_z\|_2dz\leq\|q\|_2\sup_{s\leq t}\intop_0^s\|u_z\|_2dz\leq2\lambda t\sup_{s\leq t}\|u_s\|_2$$

For $t<\frac{1}{2}\lambda$ this implies $u_t=0$. Recursively, we get $u_t=0$ for all $t\geq0$; hence $p_t=r_t$. $\square$

---

**My questions**

Here's what i don't understand about the proof.

1. How can it be shown that $\frac{d}{dt}p_t=qp_t$? I was able to verify the right-hand derivative ([Theorem 11](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197916/additivity-of-the-matrix-exponential-of-infinite-matrices)), but not the left-hand derivative.
2. What's $\|\cdot\|_2$? It looks like the Euclidean norm on the vectorized argument, but the Euclidean norm could evaluate to $\infty$ for some matrices.
3. Why is
   $$\sup_{s\leq t}\|u_s\|_2\leq\sup_{s\leq t}\intop_0^s\|qu_z\|_2dz$$
4. Why is
   $$\sup_{s\leq t}\intop_0^s\|qu_z\|_2dz\leq\|q\|_2\sup_{s\leq t}\intop_0^s\|u_z\|_2dz$$
5. What does it mean "recursively"? It doesn't look like a proof by induction. What's the variable of recursion?